# Compiling c++ from command line using nmake or another tool like batch script

Tags: c++, batch-file, g++, mingw-w64, nmake

I have multiple c++ files in a directory, but at a moment, I need to compile only one of them. I am using Windows 10 with mingw-w64.

Currently I am individually writing command like `g++ abc.cpp -o abc` plus some flags, but I need to automate this, for example, writing only some command like `compile abc.cpp`.

I am looking through nmake, but there doesn't seem any simple tutorial and I am stuck for some time on this.

Is there any easy tool for this job, or how can it be done in nmake. I am using VSCode

**Edit**

In comment of KamilCuk I come to know about batch script which can also be used

Comment: `s there any easy tool for this job` Seeking external tools is offtopic for stackoverflow. I would (strongly) recommend `cmake`.

Comment: @KamilCuk after using cmake, what is the process of compiling, can I use command like `compile one.cpp` or `compile two.cpp` where these two are in same folder

Comment: @KamilCuk SO I have to write this line again and again : `cmake --build <the source dir> --target one.o`

Comment: That depends on your configuration, any custom setup will require a bit of your work. But stilll you can configure cmake and then `cmake --build <the build dir> --target <proper path to one.obj file>` with most build systems. `I have to write this line again and again` what do you mean? Usually you compile a program or a library, not single source files (well, unless you are writing it yourself or living without a build system that automates that).

Comment: Actually my objective is to reduce the line that I use to compile: `g++ one.cpp -o one` to a smaller line maybe `compile one.cpp`. But I need it to work for other files also like `compile two.cpp`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214115/discussion-between-jeea-and-kamilcuk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best, simplest method for this is to use a Makefile. I believe mingw has make capabilities.

All you have to do is simply create a file called "Makefile" with no extensions.

In the Makefile add the following lines

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = PUT YOUR FLAGS HERE
abc: abc.cpp
     $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o abc
```

Then when you want to compile abc, simply run `make abc` in the command line.

Edit: Support for custom files

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = PUT YOUR FLAGS HERE
main: $(FILE).cpp
     $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(FILE)
```

This new makefile, reads in the filename from the command line.
You can simply run: `make FILE=abc` and it will build abc.cpp and send it to -o abc

Comment: Thank you for answer but what I am looking for is that I have various different file, like `abc.cpp` or `def.cpp`. Using this I will need to change the makefile again and again

Comment: @jeea I updated it to take in arguments from the command line.

Comment: thanks mate just can you tell me is it possible to pass argument without writing `FILE=..` I mean directly `make abc.cpp` where `abc.cpp` is automatically passed to variable in makefile?

Comment: I don't think so but what you could do is write a shell/bash script. Create like build.sh and give it some script like:
````make FILE=$1````, you may have to mess around with this, but if you have the script file, running this would only be ````./build.sh abc````, you could then set an alias so typing ````compile```` runs ````./build.sh````, then you can finally run your desired output: ````compile abc````. If you need more clarification, feel free to reach out to me.

Comment: Thanks!! I also needed to run it now, something like `compileAndRun abc.cpp`, what command do i need to add in makefile??

Comment: Don't put it in the Makefile the Makefile should only consist of the operations to build the object files and produce the executable, in your bash/batch/shell script you would run ````./a.out```` or whatever the name of your executable is, after the make command.